# Should an accent be used before or after boldface?

Tags: bold, accents, vector

When I want to have an accent (e.g. hat, tilde or dot) be used on a vector. Should that accent also be boldface, or not? E.g. should I write `\mathbf{\hat{a}}` or `\hat{\mathbf{a}}`?

I have also asked this on the [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3593288/759487), where it has been concluded that this is a matter of opinion, but I would like to know what the Latex community thinks about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I try a simple document

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
$\mathbf{\hat{a}}$ $\hat{\mathbf{a}}$
\showoutput
\end{document}
```

the log file will contain

```latex
....\mathon
....\vbox(6.94444+0.0)x5.59023
.....\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x0.0, shifted -0.07986
......\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 ^
.....\kern-4.44444
.....\hbox(4.44444+0.0)x5.59023
......\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 a
....\mathoff
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
....\mathon
....\vbox(7.08334+0.0)x5.59023
.....\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x0.0, shifted 0.2951
......\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ^
.....\kern-4.30554
.....\hbox(4.44444+0.0)x5.59023
......\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 a
....\mathoff
```

As you see, in the first case the accent is taken from the bold font

```
\OT1/cmr/bx/n/10 ^
```

whereas it's from the medium font in the second case

```
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 ^
```

My idea is that the hat should always be the same independently on what symbol it sits upon: you're placing a hat over the symbol for a variable, not making bold a “hatted” symbol.

But it's really a question of personal preference. Just be consistent.

[image]